# Don't startup spring context in uni-test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, maven-2, junit

I have web application on spring mvc and maven.
When I execute "mvn clean install" I got nullpointerexception from some uni-test.
It's happens because one of resource is null, but why ?

Uni-test:

```
package myapp.services.impl

....

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration
public class MyServiceImplTest {

    @Resource
    private MyService myService;

    @Transactional
    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity();
        myService.createSomething(entity);  // THROW - NullPointerException, myService is NULL
        ...
    }
}
```

surefire plugin in pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>myapp.env</name>
                        <value>test</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
                <junitArtifactName>org.junit:com.springsource.org.junit</junitArtifactName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And applicationContext.xml:

```
...
<context:component-scan base-package="myapp.services,myapp.services.impl"/>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/common_${myapp.env}.properties"
                              system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"
                              ignore-resource-not-found="true"/>
....
```

PS: When I execute this test in eclipse Run as JUnit Test - execute is fine without exception

Stack-trace after surefire report:

---

### Test set: myapp.services.impl.MyServiceImplTest

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.115 sec <<< FAILURE!
myapp.services.impl.MyServiceImplTest.someTest()  Time elapsed: 1.068 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myapp.services.impl.MyServiceImplTest.someTest(MyServiceImplTest.java:42)

MAVEN OUTPUT:

```
...
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.3:test (default-test) @ mywebapp ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/xxx/Work/mywebapp/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running myapp.services.impl.MyServiceImplTest
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in     org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.919 sec <<< FAILURE!


Results :

Failed tests: 
  myapp.services.impl.MyServiceImplTest.someTest()

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 41.465s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 09 00:05:06 MSD 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/70M
...
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace and the output of the context loading from the test execution.

Comment: Sure! I've added output in question after "Stack-trace after surefire report:". But I don't think that it help.

Comment: You haven't attached the output of the spring context loading. Without this my guess would be that you have a classpath issue. The application-context.xml is probably not on the maven test classpath. Generally when something works in Eclipse and not in Maven I find this is the case. Try copying the application-context.xml in the test/resources area.

Comment: Do you mean maven build output or test execution output? I don't have spring context output when I execute mvn clean install...

Comment: "Try copying the application-context.xml in the test/resources area" yes - I've tried to do but does not change anything... :(

Comment: The test execution output during the maven build should show the loading of the spring application context for the test.

Comment: Ok, I've attached output, please see

Comment: Can you show me MyService implementation and its appcontext configuration?

Comment: Immediately after the 'Running myapp.services.impl.MyServiceImplTest' you should be seeing some logging about loading the spring context. Similar to (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:315) INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/application-context.xml]. Since you are not seeing this log information I don't think the spring context is getting loaded and that is what is causing the null pointer. If fact it would look like the test isn't being runwith the SpringJUnit4Runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought but...

You say you've placed applicationContext.xml in the test/resources folder - have you recreated the directory structure you define within that directory? I.e. test/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationcontext.xml? If not, then the applicationcontext will appear in test-classes/ and won't be found according to the classpath location you've defined... If it's just in test/resources, change your @ContextConfiguration annotation to

```java
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})`
```

`